# Can we see an aggregate count of our upvotes/downvotes separately, for the Questions and Answers?

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, statistics

Can we see the total number of upvotes/downvotes we have casted, separately for the questions and answers?

Something like:

> Hey, user! you have:
>
> - upvoted 423 Questions;
> - upvoted 3432 Answers;
> - downvoted 43 Questions;
> - downvoted 53 Answers.

For example, in the Votes tab, which is privately available for every user, users can see:

1. how many votes they have casted in total (in the All sub-tab).
2. how many posts they have upvoted in total (in the Upvote sub-tab);
3. how many posts they have downvoted in total (in the Downvote sub-tab);

But what if I want to know How many *Questions* I have upvoted, or how many *answers* I have downvoted, in total?